# Help understanding Electrochemistry diagram

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, reduction-potential

[image: Potential vs Capacity of various compounds]

I was reading some literature when i came across the following figure and was wondering if someone could help explain it to me. I see on the vertical axis it is potential vs Li/Li+ and see that Oxides are at ~1.2V since the potential of lithium ion batteries are ~4V and it is a transition metal oxide are they talking about other oxides? I am assuming by potential they mean Reduction potential? Graphite is at ~0.2V Silicon at~0.3V and TiO2~1.5V but they are all used as anodes in lithium ion batteries why are they not reduced as 
$$
\Delta G = -zFE
 $$
and E is positive so dG is negative?

Comment: I understand that the cathode material is probably at an even higher potential and is thus preferentially reduced but is TiO2 also reduced?

Comment: I think the y- axis is oxidation potential rather than reduction potential, the way they are writing Li/Li+ suggests that. You have to check the context very well.

Comment: The standard reduction potential of Lithium is approx -3V and the standard reduction potential of TiO is approx -1.3V thats +1.7V like on the diagram https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)

Comment: The symbolism of Li/Li+ as a half cell is wrong since electrochemical convention is to always show the half cell as reduction e.g., Li+/Li rather.

Comment: @M. Farooq It rather follows the usual electrode description schema like <electrode>[/<coating>][/<electrolyte significant ion>]. The measured electrode potential obviously does not depend on notation.

Comment: ..as there is (electrode) potential(1) in electrostatic context and potential(2) in TD context, proportional to delta G. I suppose the diagram follows the potential(1), what is more common in applied chemistry.

Comment: @M.Farooq yeah "Vs Li/Li+" is a common way of writing it in Li-ion battery paper.